# Codeigniter: custom method in custom 'MY_Router' class

Tags: codeigniter, routes, url-routing

I have made custom method in 'MY_Router'. How and where can I call this mthod ?

MY_Router class is extending CI_Router.

Can some one guide me in this regards.

Answer (score 4):

CodeIgniter loads your MY_Router class automatically if you put it in application/core for 2.0, otherwise application/library for 17.x.

If you wish to call your method from the controller, just use $this->router->foo();

Comment: sturgeon Iam using CI 2.0. I have placed MY_Router in core folder. If I write a function "foo()" in MY_Router class. Will it("foo()") be called automatically by CI system ?

Comment: Are you writing a function or a method? If you write a method it will be available as $this->router->method_name(), if you write a function then it will be foo()... Either way this file is loaded so you can call it. Did you try debugging, doing a: exit("OH HAI!") in the file to see if it was being loaded or not? Quickest way to work out a problem :)